# nmap host up but reason = no-response

Tags: nmap

I have a strange situation.
My scanning machine is on networkA and target is on networkB.
Those networks are managed by IP pools in cisco ASA.

When I nmap the target with `-Pn -sS --reason`, I get as results the following:

```
Host is up ; port is filtered ; reason = no-response
```

What doesn't make sense is `Host is up`. It should not be there since there is no routing between those pools.

What do you think of that?

Comment: Because you used `-Pn`. https://nmap.org/book/man-host-discovery.html What happens when you do the same thing to an IP that you don't control but is impossible to reach? They should all say `Host is up`.

Comment: @schroeder Even with a simple ping sweep ( -sn ) I saw host is up. But thank you for your comment on -Pn

Comment: This is either looking like a networking issue or an nmap bug. Either way, I'm not seeing a security issue. nmap is not inherently a security tool.

Comment: @schroeder This is bugging me. It's an ASA appliance. There are 2 adress pools. No routing between them. But still, nmap -p 80 hostA says port is filtered, no-response and nonetheless Host is Up when I scan from adress pool B

Comment: @JasonKrs `-sn` does not mean "ping sweep," it means "no port scan." If you remove the port scan from a regular Nmap scan, you are left with host discovery (i.e. "ping sweep"), but you also removed host discovery with `-Pn`, so you are left with nothing.

Comment: @bonsaiviking Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

The `-Pn` option means "skip host discovery and treat every host as up." When the `-Pn` option (formerly spelled `-PN` or `-P0`) is used, every target address will show "Host is up." Since you added `--reason`, you should also see a reason for the "up" determination: "received user-set." This means the reason the target was determined to be up is that you, the user, told Nmap to consider it up.

Answer (score 0):

[Bonsaiviking's Answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/229847/163495) explains why the system is considered up, but not what `no response` means.

The complete line is `Host is up ; port is filtered ; reason = no-response`. The reason in this case refers to the filtered port, not the host.

#### What does "filtered" mean? How is it different from closed?

When a client sends a TCP handshake request, the server SHOULD either respond with a SYN-ACK response in case of a willingness to complete a handshake, or with an RST response in case of a closed port.

However, what does it mean when the client doesn't answer at all? Then the port is considered "filtered". This can be for a variety of reasons, such as a firewall configured to drop all traffic from a specific source, to a specific port, or any other number of reasons. But all nmap can see is that it gets no response, which is what it prints you as the reason.

Generally, a server that is scanned via `-Pn` and has all ports filtered is either completely offline or actually doesn't communicate with you at all.

Comment: Thank you. I understand it better (thanks God I already have a clue about TCP 3 way handshake), your comment makes it more understandable. Do you know why UDP hasa different behavior ? UDP in nmap would say open|filtered when it does not know what to think of the probe. What does it mean open|filtered for UDP ?

Comment: @botanga Yes, UDP does not have a handshake. If a host receives a UDP packet for a port that is not listening, it SHOULD reply with an ICMP message saying so. Of course, a host doesn't have to do that. And if a program is running, it can also not reply anything. Or perhaps the program is designed not to reply to anything. So `open|filtered` means that nmap got no response, so it could be open (and just nobody is replying) or it could be filtered. nmap just doesn't know.

Comment: @botanga So in short, if nmap receives an ICMP response "port unreachable", then nmap knows for sure the port is closed. If nmap receives a UDP response back, it knows for sure the port is open. If it gets no reply, it will say "open|filtered".

Comment: Awesome. I was looking for that explanation for a long time. Could not find it readily on documentation. No wonder why -sU -p- takes forever. Thank you very much

Comment: @botanga Yes, UDP is in general a lot less precise than TCP, which is why I personally only scan ports of "common" services.